# Autoimport fxml shortcut

Tags: eclipse, javafx, keyboard-shortcuts, fxml

Is there a shortcut in Eclipse which one can suddenly put all action events and IDs from a FXML to the controller ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t found a Short Cut for it, but a simple way is to Mark everything with

**CTRL + A** and after this with **CTRL + 1** you can choose the individual entrys

it is not as good as a short cut but faster then normal.